# I am not able to insert more than 5120 records in Oracle table using .net application

Tags: c#, oracle, insert, sql-loader

I am using the below code to insert bulk over 100 000 records

C# function:

```
public void ExcelUpload(DataTable dt)
    {

    try
    {
        objBus.ClearMDPreprocessed();
        lblError1.Visible = true;
        lblError1.Text = "Preparing Sheet for Validations. Please Wait...";
        using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MASTER_DATA_FOLDER"].ToString()) + "\\RawMasterData_PREPROCESSED.txt"))//(@"e:\WorkingFolder\output.txt"))
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                wr.WriteLine(row["EMPNO"] + "," + row["MODEL"] + "," + row["PRIMARY_SUPERVISOR"] + "," + row["PROJECT_MANAGER"] + "," + row["ISBPS"] + "," + row["BU"]);
            }
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Process sysprocess = new Process();
        string myCommand = @"/c SQLLDR " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ORA_CONN_MASTER_" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CONN"].ToString().Trim()].ToString().Trim() + " LOG=" + MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MASTER_DATA_FOLDER"].ToString()) + "\\MasterDataUpd_PP.Log" + " CONTROL=" + MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MASTER_DATA_FOLDER"].ToString()) + "\\Ctrl_PreProcessed_Raw.txt";
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", myCommand);
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MASTER_DATA_FOLDER"].ToString());
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        sysprocess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
        sysprocess.WaitForExit();
        if ((sysprocess.ExitCode == 4))
        {
            lblError1.Visible = true;
            lblError1.Text = "Sheet ready for Validations.Click on Validate";
            btnValidate.Visible = true;
            btnDirectUpload.Visible = true;

        }
        else
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("NOT DONE");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Ctrl_Preprocessed_Raw.txt content:

```
LOAD DATA
    INFILE RawMasterData_PREPROCESSED.txt
    BADFILE dataFile.bad
    APPEND INTO TABLE MSI_MASTER_DATA_RAW
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    TRAILING NULLCOLS
    (EMPNO,MODEL,PRIMARY_SUPERVISOR,PROJECT_MANAGER,ISBPS,BU)
```

Comment: Why are you calling out to sqlldr?  Why not just parse and load the file in the code?  Much easier to control and debug (you won't be posting to SO wondering wtf is with 5120 rows, etc).  There are other gotchas with making system calls from C# too.  And there are several good csv parser libraries that do much of the dirty work for you.

Comment: Quite strange that you parse csv-file manually in order to invoke sqlldr. Have a look at https://www.nuget.org/packages/LumenWorksCsvReader/ and get familiar with Oracle insert statements.

Comment: What happens if you run it directly against the SQL*Loader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved it using the below steps:

1) startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;   //this I made to false

2) startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;   //I have commented this line.

This resolved my issue, and I was able to insert bulk records in oracle through SQL loader without any issues with the above code. Thanks everyone for your inputs. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know C#, but `LOAD DATA INFILE ...` looks *very much* like SQL*Loader. It has a control file. In it, you can set *error limit* which terminates execution once that limit is reached. So, maybe it is set to 5120. Perhaps you could check that.

**[EDIT]**

Gosh, **of course** it is not set to 5120 ... you managed to load that much rows. Limit is, by default, set to 50. If you look at the SQL*Loader log file (as well as BAD file, if you set them to be used - and yes, you should have set it), you might find those information in there.

Comment: If you read through the code you'll note that it's invoking SQLLDR in about line 17. I added the [sql-loader] tag.

Comment: Thank you, @Bob. Didn't notice that. Must be *selective blindness*, C# code + long lines look like a jungle to me - bunch of colored letters :)

Comment: I swear (and it gets me in trouble :-) - it seems that people designing languages for the past 30 years have all been working from the same playbook. "We want something new! Exciting! Original! That looks just like C...". WTF?!?!?

Comment: @Bob, sometimes we don't decide the language being used in an application. There are some legacy applications in this world for which one has to follow old traditional steps. Changing the concepts means a lot to bigger systems.